# Made a colorcyle using js and want to terminate it's execution on the event of a click on the stop button

Tags: javascript

Here's my code

```js
var stop = document.querySelector('#stop');
var begin = document.querySelector('#start');

function rainbow() {
  var colors = ['red', 'orange', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'violet'];
  var i = 0;
  setInterval(function() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
    i++;
    i = i % colors.length;
  }, 1000);
}

begin.addEventListener('click', function() {
  rainbow()
});

function noColor() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
}

stop.addEventListener('click', function() {
  noColor()
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>JS homework</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper"></div>
  <button id="start">Start</button>
  <button id="stop">Stop</button>
  <script src="j1.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Although it does switch the `bgcolor` to white but it begins the rainbow() all over again.
I came across another interesting anomaly (if I could say so). Whenever I click on the stop button it changes the bgcolor to white but resumes from the color that was to appear from the array. For eg if I click stop after red, it would resume with orange

Answer (score 1):

It happens because the interval keeps running. You should clear it.

Use `clearInterval` and pass to it the interval you wish to cancel.

```js
var stop = document.querySelector('#stop');
var begin = document.querySelector('#start');
let interval;

function rainbow() {
  var colors = ['red', 'orange', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'violet'];
  var i = 0;
  interval = setInterval(function() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
    i++;
    i = i % colors.length;
  }, 1000);
}

begin.addEventListener('click', function() {
  rainbow()
});

function noColor() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  clearInterval(interval);
}

stop.addEventListener('click', function() {
  noColor()
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>JS homework</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper"></div>
  <button id="start">Start</button>
  <button id="stop">Stop</button>
  <script src="j1.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```